# Window load not firing in promise callback

Tags: jquery, promise, es6-promise

The following is avery basic example of what im trying to achieve. I have this working in chrome/FF but IE refuses to play nice.

```
somePromiseThatFetchesData.then((data)=>{

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var markup = functionThatGeneratesMarkup(data);
        $('body').html(markup);
    });

    $(window).on('load', function(){
        alert('all images etc from promise loaded finishes loading')
    });

});
```

The goal for me is to populate my dom with the fetched data, then wait until the assets in my generated data have loaded before firing another function. The problem is the `alert` in my callback never gets fired in `IE`

Im using the `es6-promise` polyfill for IE

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? IE doesn't support arrow functions. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you considered that you might be attaching a `load` event to the window after the load event has already happened?

Comment: yes i am using babel, the arrow function doesn't seem to be the issue. I have a couple of CORS warning in my IE console, however the data is loading just fine.

Comment: no i hadnt, when should it be attached? if i attach it before the fetch surely it would fire before the data has come back?

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer, but I've just changed it to something more sensible and less arcane. You can just attach the events right away and use `.then` inside them. Simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using a good strategy. If the `load` event has already fired before you attach the event handler, the handler will never execute.

Instead, attach the events right away and then have your promise handlers inside them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    somePromiseThatFetchesData.then((data)=>{
        var markup = functionThatGeneratesMarkup(data);
        $('body').html(markup);
    });
});

$(window).on('load', function(){
    somePromiseThatFetchesData.then((data)=>{
        alert('all images etc from promise loaded finishes loading')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but am i not making an extra request using this approach?

Comment: If `somePromiseThatFetchesData` is actually a variable and not some stand-in for some bit of code that returns a promise, then no, there would not be an extra request. If it is a stand-in, then just add this before the rest of that code: `var somePromiseThatFetchesData = codeThatCreatesThePromiseThatFetchesData();`